# EllipsePoints With LineDDA

Tags: delphi

I can draw grip points with GDI Canvas Ellipse, but the second point is painted incorrectly.  How do you prevent the effect shown?

```
procedure TFormMain.DrawMarchingAnts;
var
  iWidth: integer;
begin
  AMarchingAntsCounter := AMarchingAntsCounterStart;
  // Use LineDDA to draw each of the 4 edges of the rectangle
  LineDDA(AMarchingAntsPointA.X, AMarchingAntsPointA.Y, AMarchingAntsPointB.X, AMarchingAntsPointA.Y,
    @MarchingAnts, LongInt(
    AMarchingAntsCanvas));
  LineDDA(AMarchingAntsPointB.X, AMarchingAntsPointA.Y, AMarchingAntsPointB.X, AMarchingAntsPointB.Y,
    @MarchingAnts, LongInt(
    AMarchingAntsCanvas));
  LineDDA(AMarchingAntsPointB.X, AMarchingAntsPointB.Y, AMarchingAntsPointA.X, AMarchingAntsPointB.Y,
    @MarchingAnts, LongInt(
    AMarchingAntsCanvas));
  LineDDA(AMarchingAntsPointA.X, AMarchingAntsPointB.Y, AMarchingAntsPointA.X, AMarchingAntsPointA.Y,
    @MarchingAnts, LongInt(
    AMarchingAntsCanvas));
  if AMarchingAntsPointB.X > AMarchingAntsPointA.X then
    ARubberbandVisible := True
  else
    ARubberbandVisible := False;
  AMarchingAntsCanvas.Pen.Width := 1;
  AMarchingAntsCanvas.Pen.Color := clWhite;
  AMarchingAntsCanvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  AMarchingAntsCanvas.Ellipse(AMarchingAntsPointA.X-4, AMarchingAntsPointA.Y-4, AMarchingAntsPointA.X+4, AMarchingAntsPointA.Y+4);
  iWidth := AMarchingAntsPointB.X - AMarchingAntsPointA.X;
  AMarchingAntsCanvas.Ellipse(AMarchingAntsPointA.X-4 + iWidth, AMarchingAntsPointA.Y-4, AMarchingAntsPointA.X+4 + iWidth, AMarchingAntsPointA.Y+4);
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070123/animated-ellipse-points

Comment: How do I achieve the effect shown?

Comment: @Sertac- Is it ok to answer your own question?  I solved the refresh problem.

Comment: @Bill - Of course, please do so. You might have to wait a little bit to be able to accept your answer though.